# TEntity Remove method fails on many to many relationship that was created using database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and a database first approach.

It is a small database with a many to many relationship between Tags and BoxedItems, a table named ItemsTags holds the relationship.

I get an exception when using the scaffolded code to delete a BoxedItem:

```
db.BoxedItems.Remove(boxedItem);
db.SaveChanges();
```

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_ItemsTags_Items". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TimeBox", table "dbo.ItemsTags", column 'IdItem'.

The relationship table code is bellow. The PK for BoxedItem needs to be a Guid and for Tags is a INT IDENTITY (1, 1).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemsTags] (
    [IdItem] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [IdTag]  INT              NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemsTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdItem] ASC, [IdTag] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemsTags_Tags] FOREIGN KEY ([IdTag]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tags] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemsTags_Items] FOREIGN KEY ([IdItem]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BoxedItems] ([Id])
);
```

Would the EF auto generated code work out of the box if my BoxedItem PK was INT IDENTITY (1, 1)? EF seems to like it more for auto generated code.

Is there a smarter way to delete the BoxedItem, other than a custom SQL instruction?

Comment: That's not what the exception is telling you at all. Your `ItemsTags` table has a non-nullable foreign key to the table you're trying to delete from. In order to delete that item, you'll need to either set a new value for that foreign key, first, or make it nullable. You could also add a delete cascade, so that the offending `ItemsTags` rows is removed as well.

Comment: A great Thank You!!! That made a lot of sense and just adding ON DELETE CASCADE solved it.